# Counting number of headers in an Access Query and Finding the Max

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using VBA and I am exporting some `Access` queries to Excel. This macro is being built on the `Access` side. I have an array of queries such as:

`Qs = Array(q1, q2, q3)`

I need to `count` the number of headers in each query and find the `max`.

Based on a couple searches, I found you can use the `WorksheetFunction.Max` but I am getting an `"Object Required" error`.

Here is the code I am trying that is raising an error:

```
 WorksheetFunction.Max(Qs(0).Fields.Count, Qs(1).Fields.Count, Qs(2).Fields.Count)
```

Is there another way to do this?

P.S. I already added a reference to `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library`

Comment: What are q1, q2, and q3?

Comment: Hey! thanks for the response. q1 q2 and q3 are the names of the queries in Access

Comment: So you mean they are string values?  And `Debug.Print TypeName(q1)` tells you 'String'?

Comment: Yes, q1, q2, and q3 are `string` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reported that `q1`, `q2`, and `q3` are String variables which contain the names of queries.

So the problem is that a String does not have a `Fields` collection. Therefore `Qs(0).Fields.Count` triggers error #424, *"Object required"*.

If you want `Fields.Count`, you must reference it via a suitable *object*.

Since `Qs(0)` holds the name of a query, you can reference the actual `DAO.QueryDef` (the saved query) object with `CurrentDb.QueryDefs(Qs(0))`

But since you want the `Count` of that query's `Fields`, use this:

```vb
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(Qs(0)).Fields.Count
```

Another way to approach this would be to make `q1`, `q2`, and `q3` object variables instead of strings ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim q1 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim q2 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim q3 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim Qs As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
With db
    Set q1 = .QueryDefs("Query1")
    Set q2 = .QueryDefs("Query2")
    Set q3 = .QueryDefs("Query3")
End With
Qs = Array(q1, q2, q3)
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(Qs(0).Fields.Count, Qs(1).Fields.Count, Qs(2).Fields.Count)
```

I tested that sample code in Access 2010 and it prints the maximum `Fields.Count` of the 3 queries.  But I don't know whether this suggestion will easily integrate with the rest of your code.  Hopefully it points you to something useful.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, really nice job explaining why I was getting the error and providing an explanation of the solution needed.